# Existence of an axiom question in relation to $\mathsf{Infinity}$

Tags: logic, set-theory

**Original Post**
This may be a stupid question, but does there axist an axiom $\phi$ that is *independent* of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, and **not equivalent** to the axiom of $\mathsf{Infinity}$,  such that $\left(\mathsf{ZFC} -\mathsf{Infinity}+\phi\right) \vdash \mathsf{Infinity}$? Can such a $\phi$ exist? Or will all $\phi$ be equivalent to $\mathsf{Infinity}$?
**Edit1**:
Danul's answer certainly answers the question, but I am wondering if there exists a weaker axiom $\phi$. 
**Edit2** I realize I had no idea what I meant by **weaker axiom**

**Edit3, Conclusions**
I guess I want to know whether or not  every axiom $\phi$ such that $\mathsf{ZFC}-\mathsf{Infinity} + \phi$ proves that "There exists an inductive set" is such that $\phi$ is either stronger than $\mathsf{Infinity}$ or equivalent to $\mathsf{Infinity}$ and I guess this is the case as $\left(\mathsf{ZFC} -\mathsf{Infinity} + \phi\right)  \vdash \mathsf{Infinity} \Longrightarrow \left(\phi \Longrightarrow \mathsf{Infinity}\right) \lor \left(\phi \longleftrightarrow \mathsf{Infinity}\right)$ 
In this beginning, I really just wanted to know if we could prove that a countably infinite set existed without simply postulating that *one such* exists. Can we? What is the most minimal assumption that we need to make? Is it really just $\mathsf{Infinity}$? 
**Edit4**
AH, correct, Thanks Danul. I guess what I meant was:
$$
\left(\mathsf{ZFC} -\mathsf{Infinity} + \phi\right)  \vdash \mathsf{Infinity} \Longrightarrow \left(\phi \vdash \mathsf{Infinity}\right) 
$$
As the axiom of infinity cannot be derived from the rest of the axioms of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, so it must be the case that $\phi \vdash \mathsf{Infinity}$. Steven Stadniski answered my question in the comments. Thanks everyone. 
**Edit5**
I am making all sorts of reasoning errors! We have that $$(\mathsf{ZFC} - \mathsf{Infinity} + \phi) \vdash \mathsf{Infinity} \not{\rightarrow}  \phi \vdash \mathsf{Infinity}$$ 
Because $\phi = \mathsf{Extensionality} \longrightarrow \mathsf{Infinity} $ is a counterexample. 
False logic will be the end of me.

Comment: In a way, the axiom of infinity as usually formulated has the property. Without at least some rudimentary set theory, it doesn't really say that an inductive set exists, and it certainly doesn't say that there is an infinite set.

Comment: How do you mean '$\phi$ doesn't already prove infinity'?  If $\mathsf{ZFC}-\mathsf{Infinity}+\phi\vdash\mathsf{Infinity}$ doesn't that by definition imply that $\phi$ proves Inf?  Or are you thinking in a weaker formal system than $\mathsf{ZFC}$?  When you talk about relative consistency results you have to be _very_ precise about what base systems your equivalencies are over...

Comment: I am really trying to make precise what I mean, but perhaps I'm doing a piss poor job of it.

Comment: @Rustyn: I think with a question like this, you should say *exactly* what you mean by "not equivalent" and what *exactly* you mean by "Infinity". Usually it means that there is an inductive set, but I think there are weaker formulations that imply the existence of infinite sets, for example "There exists a set with more than $1$ element which is equipotent with its own square". I might be wrong, but I think this would not imply the existence of infinite ordinals.

Comment: @Rustyn: I think something like "if (some axiom of ZFC), then infinity" should provide a counterexample. But you need to take care so that the axiom is not one of those required for the notion of inductive set to make sense.

Comment: I have edited the question above, thank you for your help in these matters. Please let me know if I need to be more explicit about anything, I am just now learning logic and set theory and I am still very new to it.

Comment: Thank you for bearing with me, and I'm sorry if this question is agitating.

Comment: $P, Q \vdash R$ does not imply $P \vdash R$ or $Q \vdash R$: e.g. let $R = P \wedge Q$ as a counterexample!

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Why does $\mathsf{ZFC} - \mathsf{Infinity} + \phi \vdash \mathsf{Infinity}$ imply that $\phi \vdash \mathsf{Infinity}$ ? Take for example $\phi = \mathsf{Extensionality} \longrightarrow \mathsf{Infinity}$. Then $\mathsf{ZFC} - \mathsf{Infinity} + \phi \vdash \mathsf{Infinity}$ but why is it the case that $\phi \vdash \mathsf{Infinity}$? How is a formal proof of $\mathsf{Infinity}$ derived from $\mathsf{Extensionality} \longrightarrow \mathsf{Infinity}$? Pardon me if I misunderstand something  obvious or have made another logic error.

Comment: So... what exactly is your question, after all the edits?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I accepted Danul's answer a long time ago. He answered most of my questions. My only remaining question is the one posted to StevenStadniski in the comment above your comment in regard to his first comment on this thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make $\varphi$ be Axiom of infinity plus $GCH$. Then you have that $ZFC-\text{infinity}+\varphi\vdash\text{infinity}$, but $\varphi$ is definitely much stronger than $\text{infinity}$.

Edit: I don't know what you mean by weaker axioms. But remember that $ZFC$ can produce a model (in-fact a countable transitive model) for $ZFC-\text{infinity}+\neg{\text{infinty}}$, namely the hereditarily finite sets (or $V_{\omega}$ if you prefer). So in a sense you can't really be any weaker.

Edit 2: At your current edit (You should keep track of the edits btw or else the entire conversation will become useless, so maybe not delete the original post) the question is trivial. Let $\varphi=\neg{\text{infinity}}$. Now the right hand side is trivial because of the way $\implies$ is defined.

Edit 3: Edit 2 is meant to show that your reasoning is faulty. $\neg{\text{infinity}}$ and $\text{infinity}$ are contradictory, but if you set $\varphi=\neg{\text{infinity}}$, you still get $ZFC-\text{infinity}+\varphi\vdash \text{Infinity}\implies(\varphi\implies\text{Infinity})\lor(\varphi\iff{\text{infinity}})$.

For an answer to your informal question, see the first edit for this solution.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. This axiom has to combine with the other ZFC axioms to prove there exists an infinite set anyway. Otherwise your question itself doesn't make sense.

Comment: You need to make your question more precise. The way you have formulated this I can give an even more trivial answer that I already did: Take $\varphi=\exists{x}x\neq{x}$. This will prove everything on its own and has nothing to do with infinity (or you don't really need to worry about models) whatsoever

Comment: I have edited the question and come to a conclusion.

Comment: In this model for $\mathsf{ZFC} - \text{infinity} + \lnot \text{infinity}$, $V_{\omega}$ is a **class** though right? and not a set?

Comment: I think we have $ \mathbf{ON}^{V_\omega} = \omega $. So $ \omega $ is a proper class and $ V_\omega $ is "nothing at all", i.e. not definable.

Comment: It is the universe for the model and is not a regarded as a set inside the model. However it is the class $x=x$ in this case. (To see that it is not a set we can carry out the argument the class of all sets is not a set inside of $V_{\omega}$).

Comment: You are right, my previous comment is unclear about that. Indeed, $ V_\omega = \mathbf{WF}^{V_\omega} $ and $ (\mathbf{V} = \mathbf{WF} )^{V_\omega} $. (The latter holds by foundation inside $ V_\omega $.) To carry out the argument that $ \mathbf{V} $ is not a set needs only very few axioms of $ \mathsf{ZF} $ and holds in all reasonable models.

Answer (score -2):

If you are looking for a simpler, more intuitive alternative to the ZF axiom of infinity -- reading between the lines here -- you might consider simply assuming that there exists a set $S$ on which there is defined an injective, but not surjective function $f$, i.e. $S$ is Dedekind-infinite. Could it get more *minimal*? From such a set, you can extract at least one subset $N$ that satisfies Peano's axioms where $f$ serves as the successor function.